# PHP extension imagick 3.5.0 for PHP 8 : installation on macos fails

Tags: php, macos, imagick

When I try to run the following command

```
pecl install imagick
```

Then the installation end up with:

```
imagemagick/7.0.11-9/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-9/lib -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI
cc ${wl}-flat_namespace ${wl}-undefined ${wl}suppress -o .libs/imagick.so -bundle  .libs/imagick_file.o .libs/imagick_class.o .libs/imagickdraw_class.o .libs/imagickpixel_class.o .libs/imagickpixeliterator_class.o .libs/imagick_helpers.o .libs/imagick.o .libs/imagickkernel_class.o .libs/shim_im6_to_im7.o  -lgomp -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-9/lib /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-9/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.dylib -L/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/lib -L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-9/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.dylib  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-9/lib
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [imagick.la] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

The reason seems to be that the compilation of the last version of imagick (3.5.0) has changes that require this library. It's impossible to install a lower version because they are not compatible with PHP 8.0.

Any idea how to get rid of this error on macos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update 22 July 2021

As of 22 July 2021, version 3.5.1 is stable in the `pecl` channel and can be used to compile imagick for both PHP 7 and PHP 8.

```
pecl install imagick
```

The general command will not fail anymore

### Old Answer

Version 3.5 currently can't compile on MAC because of missing/broken support for `gomp` of the MAC `gcc` compiler.

Best fix is to install version 3.4.4

```
pecl install imagick-3.4.4
```

More info [here](https://coding.andreaolivato.com/fix-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-when-installing-imagick-35-via-php-pecl-on-mac)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. But according to the changelog, only imagick 3.5 is compatible with PHP 8.0...

Comment: Updated with the new stable version `3.5.1`, not the RC

Comment: Also works in docker image of php8.0-fpm

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for this issue by manually installing the extension. The only issue with it is that it does not appear in the pecl installed extensions after the installation is done and can't be uninstalled from pecl. Nonetheless I'm providing the answer I found here:

Run the following commands

```sh
cd path/to/installation/is/going/to/be/made
pecl bundle imagick
cd imagick
mv config.m4 config.m4.bak
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyongpil/imagick/2a2b924b9d25c8ef4a677b72e6868fbc7c9e01cc/config.m4
```

To explain the previous process command line by command line:

1. Place yourself in the folder where you are going to make the install
2. Download and expand the source files
3. Enter the source folder
4. Backup the original `config.m4` file for safety purposes
5. Download modified `config.m4` file to fix `gomp` issue as explained [here](https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/430)

And finally simply continue with the manual installation process

```sh
phpize
./configuration
make
sudo make install
```

After this, you should be good to go to use the latest `imagick` extension for PHP. For `PHP 8.0` and `imagick 3.5.0` the `so` file is located at `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/imagick.so`

Comment: Actually there's no more modification required. Building the master branch will be good enough as it's fixed on the project repository. https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/449

Answer (score 0):

A new version has been tag and contains the build configuration fixed! You can install it with this command:

```
pecl install imagick-3.5.1
```

*(without the version it should now work)*